# Having problems getting script to continue using workflow after dcpromo /unattend

Tags: powershell, workflow, powershell-ise

```
Workflow Rename-DC
{
   dcpromo /unattend:C:\Payload\AnswerFile.xml

   Checkpoint-Workflow

   New-ADOrganizationalUnit -Name "Admin" -Path "DC=ProjectX,DC=com"

   Add-KdsRootKey EffectiveImmediately 

   New-ADServiceAccount -Name "Test Account" -DNSHostName "DC1.ProjectX.com" -Enabled $true

   New-ADUser -Name "HelpDesk" -GivenName "Helpdesk" -Surname "" -SamAccountName helpdesk -UserprincipalName helpdesk@ProjectX.com -Path "OU=Admin,DC=ProjectX,DC=com"

   Unregister-ScheduledJob -Name RenameDCResume
}

$Admin = "Administartor"
$Password = ConvertTo-SecureString -String "Passw0rd" -AsPlainText -Force
$Cred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PsCredential($Admin, $Password)
$AtStartup = New-JobTrigger -AtStartup
Register-ScheduledJob -Name RenameDCResume `
                      -Credential $Cred `
                      -Trigger $AtStartup `
                      -ScriptBlock {Import-Module PSWorkflow; `
                      Get-Job -Name RenameDomainController -State Suspended `
                      | Resume-Job}

Rename-DC -JobName RenameDomainController
```

Looking for some help with my workflow in PowerShell. the plan is to get the script to continue after the computer reboots for installation of the DC at line 3. However, the script doesn't seem to be continuing as planned at start up. Any ideas what I can do to correct this? Also, is the checkpoint after the dcpromo correct? Will it still take a checkpoint or will it ignore this as the reboot has already begun? would a PSPersist work better? Thanks in anticipation.

Comment: Since dcpromo got deprecated years ago (2012 if I remember correctly) I would strongly advise against using this in scripts you design nowadays. There is no reason I can think of why you would use this command in a script (installing DCs with a legacy OS on them is a very bad practice). You can (and should) use Install-ADDSDomainController to install a new DC.

Comment: ok didn't realise that. Was just for ease of use to use an answer file. How does the workflow look?

Comment: Now I remember why I was using dcpromo within the workflow. for install-addsdomaincontroller you need to supply credentials which isn't allowed within workflows as it doesn't support user interaction, do you have a workaround for this?